# Perl Win32::OLE Print all attributes of an AD object

Tags: perl, active-directory, win32ole

I use the following code to get the value of the attribute NAME of an AD computer object:

```
$compObj = Win32::OLE->GetObject("LDAP://cn=$computername,dc=test,dc=com");
print "$compObj->{Name}";
```

How can I get information of all the attributes stored in the object? I miss a method like a dump function or something like that. How can I find out which possible attributes are existent?

Comment: `use Data::Dumper;` `print Dumper $compObj;`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I get no output but this warning: print() on unopened filehandle Dumper. Do you know what I can do here?

Comment: Make sure you include the use line.

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
foreach $key (keys %$compObj){
  print $key."\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jens. First, I changed it to `foreach $key (keys %compObj)` without the Dollar. But unfortunately the outputs keeps being empty. I do not understand why ...

Comment: @Hamstibamsti Because  `$compObj`is a reference to a hash and has to be dereferenced. `%compObj` is a new hash

Comment: Thanks again for responding. Your explanation is very good. Thanks. Unfortunately the output is still empty ... :-(

Comment: @Hamstibamsti then use Data:Dumper to see the Content of `$compObj`